# Getting my JQuery to work with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I want to populate a select element with the following function. It works in FF and Chrome, however the drop downs are blank in IE:

```
function resetMajor(target) {
    var vname = jQuery(target).attr('name');

    var majorId = jQuery(target).val();

    var highestDegreeCategory = jQuery('#highestLevel :selected').val();
    jQuery(target).empty();
    jQuery(target).append(jQuery("<option>").val("0").html(" -- Select -- "));

    jQuery.each(jsonMajors, function(index, element){
        var isAvailable = true;
        var vname =element.majorName;

        if (vname.indexOf("(") > 0)
           vname = vname.substring(0,vname.indexOf("("));

        if ("UGRD"==highestDegreeCategory && "GRAD"==element.category){
            isAvailable = false;
        }

        if (isAvailable){
            jQuery(target).append(jQuery("<option>").val(element.majorId).html(vname));
            if (element.majorId == majorId){
                jQuery(target).children(":last").attr("selected","selected");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

jQuery - jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.2 and IE 10

Comment: What version of jQuery? What version of IE?

Comment: What versions of jQuery and IE are you using?

Comment: What is jsonMajors? Where does it come from? Have you checked that this is being populated in IE?

Comment: jQuery - jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.2 and IE 10

Comment: upgrade your jquery first

Comment: did you try .append('<option value="0">select</option>'); ? and use jquery 1.7

Comment: please update with a jsfiddle.net

Comment: Upgraded to jQuery 1.9.1 and also with 1.10.1 and the problem still exist.

Comment: Anything in IE's error console?

Comment: i suspect this might be the issue `jQuery(target).empty();` but i don't know why try using palin javascript `target.innerHTML = ''`

Comment: Do you get the "--select--" option? I do in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chy34/

Answer (score 1):

I am suspecting below piece of code

```
jQuery(target).append(jQuery("<option>").val("0").html(" -- Select -- "));
jQuery(target).append(jQuery("<option>").val(element.majorId).html(vname));
```

Can you Please change it like below and check

```
jQuery(target).append('<option value="0"> -- Select -- </option>'));
jQuery(target).append('<option value="' + element.majorId + '">' + vname + '</option>'));
```